# How to find the differential equation satisfying $y=x|x|$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to find the differential equation satisfying $y=x|x|$?

I am facing this type of problem(Solution with $|.|$ sign) for the first time. please give hints. Thank  You in advance.

Comment: There are infinitely many differential equations for which y = x|x| is a solution?

Comment: can you give one? what would be the order and degree of each one?

Comment: You can find one by taking the derivative of both sides with respect to $x$.

Comment: then there would be a problem with differentiability while applying the product rule at $x=0%

Comment: @N.Maneesh: what kind of problem ?

Comment: If you give no additional constraint, the differential equation of zero-th order $y=x|x|$ is the easiest to obtain.

Comment: The main hint one can give here is to treat separately the cases $x>0$ and $x<0$. This yields $$y=-x^2$$ if $x<0$ and $$y=x^2$$ if $x>0$ hence $$y'=-2x$$ if $x<0$ and $$y'=2x$$ if $x>0$, which can be expressed as a single differential equation in several ways, for example, $$y'=2|x|$$ or even, since $x$ and $y$ have the same sign, $$y'=2\mathrm{sign}(y)\cdot\sqrt{|y|}$$ amongst other solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the hint above to get
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 2|x|$$

Comment: Which can be written $xy'=2y$ to get rid of the absolute value.

Comment: Well spotted. Btw, I think you mean xy'=2y?

Comment: I think that's what I wrote. (I updated before your comment came.)